BERT-NER ai returns O (=Outside of a named entity) for every token
I am trying to integrate an BERT-NER ai in my android app. I am using Java and ONNX to load the ai, tokenize input and get the output. I am able to tokenize it correctly and load the model but the model gives me wrong labels. The model is from here: https://huggingface.co/dslim/bert-base-NER
I used the test string 'My name is Wolfgang and I live in Berlin' and it was supposed to mark Wolfgang as a person and Berlin as a location, but it marked the whole sentence as O.
Link to the tokenizer: https://github.com/jadepeng/bertTokenizer
My MainActivity.java:

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.java_bert.tokenization.BertTokenizer;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import ai.onnxruntime.OnnxTensor;
import ai.onnxruntime.OrtEnvironment;
import ai.onnxruntime.OrtException;
import ai.onnxruntime.OrtSession;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            testTokenizer();
        } catch (IOException | OrtException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in tokenizing or running ONNX model", e);
        }
    }

    private void testTokenizer() throws IOException, OrtException {
        File vocabFile = createTempFileFromAsset("vocab.txt");
        BertTokenizer bertTokenizer = new BertTokenizer(vocabFile.getAbsolutePath());

        String text = "I am Wolfgang and I live in Berlin.";
        Map<String, OnnxTensor> inputMap = bertTokenizer.tokenizeOnnxTensor(List.of(text));

        OrtEnvironment env = OrtEnvironment.getEnvironment();
        File modelFile = createTempFileFromAsset("bert_ner_model.onnx");
        OrtSession.SessionOptions sessionOptions = new OrtSession.SessionOptions();
        OrtSession session = env.createSession(modelFile.getAbsolutePath(), sessionOptions);

        try (OrtSession.Result results = session.run(inputMap)) {
            float[][][] embeddings = (float[][][]) results.get(0).getValue();

            // Define the mapping from label ids to label names
            Map<Integer, String> id2label = new HashMap<>();
            id2label.put(0, "O");
            id2label.put(1, "B-MISC");
            id2label.put(2, "I-MISC");
            id2label.put(3, "B-PER");
            id2label.put(4, "I-PER");
            id2label.put(5, "B-ORG");
            id2label.put(6, "I-ORG");
            id2label.put(7, "B-LOC");
            id2label.put(8, "I-LOC");

            List<String> tokens = bertTokenizer.tokenize(text);

            for (int i = 1; i < tokens.size() + 1; i++) {  // Start from 1 to skip the [CLS] token
                float[] tokenEmbeddings = embeddings[0][i];
                // Find the label with the highest score (argmax)
                float maxScore = Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
                int maxIndex = -1;
                for (int k = 0; k < tokenEmbeddings.length; k++) {
                    if (tokenEmbeddings[k] > maxScore) {
                        maxScore = tokenEmbeddings[k];
                        maxIndex = k;
                    }
                }
                String predictedLabel = id2label.get(maxIndex);
                Log.d(TAG, "Token: " + tokens.get(i - 1) + ", Label: " + predictedLabel);
            }
        }

        session.close();
    }


    private File createTempFileFromAsset(String assetName) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open(assetName);
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile(assetName, null, getCacheDir());
        tempFile.deleteOnExit();
        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }
        return tempFile;
    }

}`

**Output:**
[output of the program](https://i.sstatic.net/VC2VGc6t.png)

Token: i, Label: O
Token: am, Label: O
Token: wolf, Label: O
Token: ##gan, Label: O
Token: ##g, Label: O
Token: and, Label: O
Token: i, Label: O
Token: live, Label: O
Token: in, Label: O
Token: be, Label: O
Token: ##rlin, Label: O
Token: ., Label: O


**The output was supposed to be like this:**
Token: I, Label: O
Token: am, Label: O
Token: Wolfgang, Label: B-PER
Token: and, Label: O
Token: I, Label: O
Token: live, Label: O
Token: in, Label: O
Token: Berlin, Label: B-LOC
Token: ., Label: O


I tried using a different tokenizer and tflite instead of ONNX but tflite doesnt support INT32 or INT64 which I needed.

